# Problem with gems on windows desktop docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, rubygems

I have issue with gems of rails app[enter image description here][1] in docker.
My system: Windows 10 pro, docker desktop, ubuntu 22.04

I have created a container, a database. But when starting my application, I get the following error. Below is a screenshot of my error. bundle install - do not solve this problem.

My Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ruby:2.7.5
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . /app
    RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs
    RUN bundle install --without=test
    EXPOSE 3000
    CMD ["bash"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:cached
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    command: >
      bash -c "bundle exec rails s -p 3030"
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432
      BINDING: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: 3030
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
volumes:
  bundle:
  postgres:
  redis:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/izW1o.png

Comment: Yes, link on bottom of post

Comment: Sorry, deleted my previous comment. Its talking about a syntax error. can you share the file in question in your above post?

Comment: What do you mean? which file?

Comment: it might be me just being silly but its referencing an error (in your error image) at ```@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons'``` or am i wrong? if that file doesnt exist that might also be an issue

Comment: I have comented my import of bootstrap icon and delete //= require '@nathanvda/cocoon' and my app its work.

Comment: = require '@nathanvda/cocoon' и = require '@nathanvda/cocoon', а также @import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons' -- if i delete this my app work correct

Comment: yeah i imaging so, as thats what the error is saying. do you have that file? do you need it for your app?

Comment: Yes, it used at my application